# sqlserver create admin for one database

Tags: sql-server

I have an sqlserver and a root admin that can change all databases

Now I want to add another user that can only administer the 'ProjectA' database

I am not sure what I need to do to achieve my goal:

```
CREATE USER porjectAdmin WITH PASSWORD = '12345'

USE ProjectA
GRANT "EVERYTHING" ON "EVERYTHING"
```

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to do this:

Grant CONTROL on the database to the user:

```
use SomeDatabase;
grant control to SomeUser;
```

Add the user to the db_owner role:

```
use SomeDatabase;
alter role db_owner add member SomeUser;
```

Make the login the real owner of the database:

```
alter authorization on database::foo to SomeLogin;
```